# How to find best match of Disease from Symptoms?

Tags: mysql

Am working on an application that helps user to enter symptoms and gets disease.

I have the following database table with information about symptoms, diseases, and disease-symptoms which associates the two tables, as shown below:

```
DISEASE_T   SYMPTOMS    disease-symptoms
==========  ==========  ========
DISEASE_ID  SYMPTOM_ID  DISEASE_ID
VALUE       VALUE       SYMPTOM_ID
```

I want to search user selected symptoms, which are array of symptoms id in disease-symptoms table and return top 5 matching disease IDs, based on, where most of the symptoms are matching with each disease.

For example, user select symptoms are 1,2,3 (cough,cold,headache)

```
DISEASE_T      SYMPTOMS_T  disease-symptoms
=========      ==========  ===============
1,malaria       1,cough          1,1
2,tuberculosis  2,cold           1,2
3,typhoid       3,headache       2,2
                                 2,3
                                 3,1
                                 3,2
                                 3,3
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This question is a bit vague, although that could just be me. Are you trying to build an application for a website? In that case, you could use AJAX calls to connect to the SQL database and return a result, but I would personally not use SQL for that. JSON is a lot easier and more efficient when it comes to asynchronous data-exchange.

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking us for the query? What have you tried already?

Comment: @llouk ,the illustration shown above gives an insight on what I have done so far..should I upload the whole database

Comment: @lawrencecyber. No, you should try to explain what your actual question is. E.g., what would your expected output be from the given output, and what exactly is stopping you from getting that output? Your background info is fine for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple query of your direct Disease-Symptoms table based on the symptoms you are interested in qualifying against.  The group by will give one record per disease no matter how many actual symptoms qualify.  Finally, the ORDER by in DESCENDING order will put the most matched symptoms to the top of the list.

Now, simple join to your symptoms and Disease to get the "value" descriptors for final read context output.

```
select 
      DS.Disease_ID,
      D.Value as Disease,
      group_concat( S.Value SEPARATOR ',' ) as Symptoms,
      count(*) as SymptomsMatching
   from
      Disease-Symptoms DS
         JOIN Symptoms_T S
            on DS.Symptom_ID = S.Symptom_ID
         JOIN Disease_T D
            on DS.Disease_ID = D.Disease_ID
   where
      DS.Symptom_ID IN ( 1, 2, 3 )
   group by
      DS.Disease_ID
   order by
      count(*) desc,
      D.Value
```

Comment: Your explanation is truly amazing! Thank you very much for your time and effort

Comment: I created front end form where the user enters the symptoms.So  I tried to implement your code logic in my .php file which is embedded in html form.Can you please give me a hint on how the code for handling the  form should be